# session_start returns error 503

Tags: php, http-status-code-503

My webserver returns Error 503 when running the following php script:

```
<?php
$n = 50;
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
   session_start();
   usleep(100);
   session_write_close();   
}
?>
```

However, if $n=40 then it works fine. It works in both cases on localhost. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the `session_start()` at the top of the document, right under the `<?php`

Comment: Bad!
You create an extreme server overload. Each created session will push up the HDD i/o. Your webserver can't handle if in this short time.

Comment: Why are you having to do this? Explain your requirement.